# Read the instrument data from printer port directly with computer with pyserial

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

This question is as much related to software as it is related to hardware and I posted the similar question to electronic stack exchange for hardware part.

I have an instrument which writes its output to the okidata printer. My goal is to write it directly to the computer in some text-ASCII file. The pinout from the device is shown in the image below:

[image: Pinout from device]

It is DB-25 with only 8 pin in use so I assume it is transmitting data serially. So I bought a null modem (crossover) cable with DB-25 female to DB-9 female converter and attached it to my serial port of my computer. One thing about the device is, it used to recognize whether printer is ready or not when it was plugged in the printer, thus I assume the printer had set one of the pin high if it was ready so that the device(instrument) knew that the printer was ready. If this logic should be followed, then I had to set one pin among these 8 pins to high.

I am just experimenting with pyserial and could not figure out and the device is saying that printer is not ready which means that it is not seeing one pin it wants to see high as high.

I tried setting serial RTS and DTR to false and toggled true but does not help.

Am I not understanding something here? Can somebody point me in how to approach this and replace the printer. I can also use arduino if required but I am not seeing how to for now.

Comment: A D25-RS232 or D25-USB converter will make you life much easier at the price of a few dollars.

Comment: That's what I have right now I have D25-RS232 converter I am using but I cannot even make the "printer not ready" go away from the instrument. I am pretty sure that I have to set some pin to high to make that go away but pyserial do not talk about individual pin in their documentation.

Comment: Don't use toggles, if you have some API just use `pyserial` to send commands to the printer and again `pyserial` to get a response, as for the port configuration it must be as stated by the manufacture setting RTS or DTR without understanding the port configuration is not relevant.